# How to add a maidengrid overlay to leaflet

Tags: leaflet, overlay

Is there a ready-made [maidenhead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maidenhead_Locator_System) grid overlay for Leaflet? If not, how to create it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't one, so I created my own: [Leaflet.Maidenhead](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/leaflet.maidenhead).

So with a bit of HTML like

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.maidenhead@1.0.0/src/maidenhead.js"></script>
```

and then a bit of javascript like

```
L.maidenhead({precision: 6}).addTo(map)
```

you should be able to have something that looks like

[image: leaflet.maidenhead screenshot]